# What is this type of tire?

Tags: tires

[image]

I saw this type of tire as a spare tire on a car I borrowed. It has small "spikes" covering the surface. Is this some type of winter tire? I have not seen similar before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The spikes are just from the manufacturing process and are visible on all brand new tyres, to some extent.

They are created from the vents in the mold that allows air to escape.  The vents are called spews.  If you watch any kind of casting process, you will see spews added to allow the mold to vent air.

They very quickly wear off when the tyre is used, but you may still see some on the walls of old tyres where they have not been in contact with the road.

The tyre in the photo is not special.  It looks like it has very little tread from new, which would fit with it being only there as a spare.

Comment: Very well stated. +1